# Howto close a MDI CView from CMainFrame

Tags: mfc

How do I close (using code) the last created CView in my MDI app. from the CMainFrame class ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call OnCloseDocument on the associated CDocument (which you can get by calling GetDocument on the CView instance).